# Why is my website not spanning the full width of my screen using Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, responsiveness

I am an aspiring Web Designer and Developer and my code isn't spanning the full width of my screen using the Bootstrap framework for a project I'm working on. I've built similar landing pages before and never came across this issue. The screenshots I've attached show there is empty space to the right of all my main elements in the body except the navbar and footer. The jumbotron, div and

---

tags don't span full width with a little extra to the right of it on screen. On 320px it's worse, there's a lot of space, and doesn't look professional. (Screenshots included for Desktop and 320px responsive view)

I tried spending time tweaking the code and looking for answers online and couldn't find what I'm looking for. Please take a look at my code and let me know where I'm going wrong and correct any mistake I have made. I greatly appreciate anyone who took the time to look at this and figure out the issue and provide the correct tweak to the HTML/CSS.

Thank you!

[Desktop screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2yOK.png)
[320 px screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yAPH.png)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>My Website</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,  initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body style="background-color: #f0f0f0;">
    <header class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top" style="background-color: #e3f2fd;">
        <a class="navbar-brand active" href="#">My Website</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
      
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#About">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#Services">Services</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#Contact">Contact Us</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
       
    <div><br>&nbsp;</div>

    
      <!---------------------- Opening Hero Section ---------------------->
    <div>
      <div class="jumbotron" style="background-image: url(./images/front-of-truck2.jpg); height: 672px; width: 100%; padding-top: 120px;">

        <!-- <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4">
                  <img style="position: static; width: 250px; height: 150px;" src="./images/image.jpeg"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  -->
      </div>
    </div>

        <!-------------------------------About section -------------------------------->
    <div id="About" style="background-color: #f0f0f0; height: auto; width: 100%;" class="my-4">
      <div class="container py-4">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 col-12">
            <h1 class="py-2" style="color:#0400FF; letter-spacing: 1px;">About Us</h1>
            <h2 class="text-primary pt-2" style="font-weight: 500;">
               A Lores Ipsum company.
            </h2>
          </div>
            <br>
          <div class="col-md-6 col-12">
            <center>
              <img style="width: 100%; height: auto; border: 2px solid #ff8400;" alt="Black and White Semi-Transportation Trucks" src="./images/black-and-white-semi-trucks2.jpg"/>
            </center>
          </div>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>

        <div><hr></div>

        <!--------------------------------------Services section ------------------------------------>
    <div id="Services" class="my-4">
      <div class="container py-4 mt-5" style="opacity: .70;">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 col-12">
            <center class="pt-2">
                <img style="width: 100%; height: auto; border: 2px solid #ff8400;" alt="Black and White Semi-Transportation Trucks" src="./images/black-and-white-semi-trucks2.jpg"/>
            </center>
          </div>
          <br>
          <div class="col-md-6 col-12">
            <h1 class="" style="color:#0400FF; letter-spacing: 1px;">
                Services Provided
              </h1>
              <ul class="text-primary" style="font-weight: 500;">
                <li style="padding-bottom: 5px;">Lores Ipsum</li>
                <li style="padding-bottom: 5px;">Lores Ipsum</li>
                <li style="padding-bottom: 5px;">Lores Ipsum</li>
                <li>Lores Ipsum</li>
            </ul>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div><hr></div>

        <!--------------------------Contact Us section --------------------------------->
    <div id="Contact" class="top my-4" style="background-color: #f0f0f0; height: auto; width: 100%;">
        <div class="container py-4">
          <div class="row">
            <!-- <div class="col-md-4 col-12">
                <center>
                  <img style="width: 100%; height: 240px; border: 2px solid #ff8400;" alt="logo" src="./images/handshake-resized.jpg"/>
                </center>
            </div>  
              <br>      -->
            <div class="col-md-7 col-12">
                <h1 class="py-2" style="color:#0400FF; letter-spacing: 1px;">Contact Us</h1>
                <h3 class="text-primary pt-2" style="font-weight: 500;">
                    <span>
                      Customer Service <br> Lores Ipsum
                    </span>
                </h3>
            </div>
              <br>
            <div class="col-md-5 col-12">
              <center>
                <img style="width: 100%; height: 240px; border: 2px solid #ff8400;" alt="Customer Service" src="./images/customer-service.jpeg"/>
              </center>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div><hr></div>

      <!----------------------------Apply Now ------------------------------------------>
    

<div id="Apply">
    <div class="container py-4 mt-2" style="opacity: .70;">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-12">
          <center class="pt-2">
              <img style="width: 100%; height: auto; border: 2px solid #ff8400;" alt="Skyline Semitruck" src="./images/semi-truck2.jpg"/>
          </center>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-12">
          <h1 class="text-center" style="color:#0400FF; letter-spacing: 1px;">
              Apply Now!
            </h1>
            <br><br><br>
            <center>
            <button type="button" class="btn" style="border: 1px solid #00fbff;">
                <h4>
                    <a href="">Apply Here!</a>
                </h4>
            </button>
        </center>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  

<footer class="row footer" style="background-color: #00fbff;" valign="bottom">
  <p class="pl-5 pt-1" style="color: #0400ff; font-weight: 500; font-size: 16px;">Lores Ipsum</p>
</footer>

<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The container usually has a margin or padding on the sides. You also have code in there that is not needed and also more importantly not supported by html5 ie:`<div><hr></div>` and the `<center>` tag. Just thought id let you know

Comment: Use your browser's built in Inspector functionality to solve this in a matter of minutes

Comment: @Brian thanks man. What tags would you recommend to replace the <div> to make the elements in the body of the page span the full width of the screen across all devices?

Comment: @Martin, I've tried doing this and couldn't figure this out which is why I'm asking. Any ideas?

Comment: @Millenial_Guy89 - You don't have to put the `<hr/>` inside a div. You can just use `<hr/>`. You should get rid of the `<center>` tag completely. Replace it with a `<div>` or even better yet a `<section>` . In order to align the content to the center in that div or section you can use css `text-align:center`. Then one last tip for you. If you specify `width: 100%` on your images you should get rid of the `height` property where you have `height: 240px;`. Otherwise your images will scale distorted. I also checked your code. I don't see any padding on the sides.

Comment: @Millenial_Guy89 - See this article on how to inspect your code to find the issues. It is a very useful tool - https://www.lifewire.com/get-inspect-element-tool-for-browser-756549

Answer (score 4):

When using bootstrap, you need to make sure all your content is wrapped in a bootstrap container. I didn't look thorugh all your code but I added a container class to the `body` tag, which decreased the space around the tags:
`<body class="container-fluid">`.

See here: https://www.codeply.com/p/MZxoobGSWw

Does this solve your issue?